# Naming image files and alt tags for wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, file, seo

Do the same rules apply for SEOing image files in wordpress as they do in other formats.
I have a flash gallery on WP. Just for examply... I need to post 10 pictures of men's hair styles..  Would I want to use a first name IE Gary's Hair Style and so on... or can I just use
Hair Style Picture 1 and so on?
Also please? Would this example work ok or is this keyword stuffing?

```
<img src=”../hair/style1.jpg” width=”100″ height=”100″ alt=”cute-hair-styly” />
<img src=”../hair/style2.jpg” width=”100″ height=”100″ alt=”short-hair-styly” />
```

Comment: **NOTE:** You have some strange quote entitites in your code, you might want to replace those with standard quotes, ie. `'` or `"` ...

Answer (score 0):

even though this should be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

this is ok. just make sure to get rid of the `-`'s between the `alt=""`. ex `alt="cute hair style"` is fine.

you can also include the `title=""` attribute but that can get annoying sometimes.